# NextJS 14 using an external js script works on local but not on Vercel

Tags: dom, next.js

I've been stuck for a while with this. I try no load an appointment form using a JS integration inside my NextJS 14 website.

Here is the component:

```
'use client'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LoadingSkeleton from './loadingSkeleton';
interface CustomWindow extends Window {
  planity?: {
    key: string;
    primaryColor: string;
    appointmentContainer?: HTMLElement | null;
    options?: {
      onServiceAdd?: () => void;
    };
  };
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

const PlanityWidget: React.FC = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.getElementById('myContainerId');

    // Charger les scripts
    const polyfillsScript = document.createElement('script');
    polyfillsScript.src = 'https://d2skjte8udjqxw.cloudfront.net/widget/production/polyfills.latest.js';
    polyfillsScript.async = true;

    polyfillsScript.onload = () => {
      const appScript = document.createElement('script');
      appScript.src = 'https://d2skjte8udjqxw.cloudfront.net/widget/production/app.latest.js';
      appScript.async = true;

      appScript.onload = () => {
        // Une fois que les deux scripts sont chargés, set up window.planity
        const customWindow = window as CustomWindow;

        if (customWindow.planity) {
          customWindow.planity = {
            key: 'MY_KEY_HERE',
            primaryColor: '#2a6259',
            appointmentContainer: container,
            options: {
              onServiceAdd: function () {
                window.scroll(0, 0);
              },
            },
          };
          setLoading(false);
        }

      };

      document.head.appendChild(appScript);
    };

    document.head.appendChild(polyfillsScript);

    // Nettoyer les scripts lors du démontage du composant
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(polyfillsScript);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <LoadingSkeleton />}
      <div id="myContainerId"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlanityWidget;
```

I have exactly the same errors, both on Vercel and my local environment using Chrome Developer Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()


2app.latest.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(error: https://d2skjte8udjqxw.cloudfront.net/static/js/0.latest.chunk.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.a (app.latest.js:1:873)
```

Actually, when I load it locally (`npm run dev`), it works perfectly. But when sent on Vercel, the form is not loading at all. It seems like the DOM is locked.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any errors inside the dev console? If so, update your post to include them.